# pattern matching regex callbacks

Tags: python, regex

I have a number of regex patterns and text on which I need to match the pattern.

The easiest way, I can go through them all by for-loop and check who matches.
But in my opinion, this is ineffective.
I tried to concatenate all the patterns into a single pattern (Using or operator)

My regex:

```
/image/(\d+)
/report/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)
```

To

```
(?P<match1>/image/(\d+))|(?P<match2>(/report/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)))
```

It works, but then I need to check if match1 or match2 is not 'None', I wonder if there is a way to improve it with a lookup table.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like there is no need for the named capture groups. In fact, you don't need any of the capture groups: `/image/\d+|/report/\d+/\d+/\d+`

Comment: Is the purpose of your regex to validate or extract data?

Comment: Validate the data

Comment: Okay, so my comment is relevant.

Comment: I need because I want to know which pattern match

Answer (score 0):

If you use the named capture groups, you could look into the [groupdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict)

> Return a dictionary containing all the named subgroups of the match,
> keyed by the subgroup name. The default argument is used for groups
> that did not participate in the match; it defaults to None.

**Note** that if you are using patterns that could have the same matches, the first pattern is matched due to the alternation.

If you want to know all the patterns that have a match, I think you would still have to use a loop to test all of them.

To get the matches only, you don't have to use separate capture groups around the digits.

```
(?P<match1>/image/\d+)|(?P<match2>/report/\d+/\d+/\d+)
```

Example using the groupdict():

```
import re

pattern = r"(?P<match1>/image/\d+)|(?P<match2>/report/\d+/\d+/\d+)"
s = "/image/5"
m = re.search(pattern, s)

if m:
    print(m.groupdict())
```

Output

```
{'match1': '/image/5', 'match2': None}
```